# What is abbreviated to "penn'"

Tags: german-to-english, meaning

I'm translating some song lyrics to English from [here](http://rapgenius.com/Cro-traum-lyrics).

> Und wenn du mich da draußen grade hörst
>    Dann bitte warte kurz auf mich, ich bin direkt bereit und fahr los
>    Doch wenn nicht, gehe ich einsam ins Bett
>    Und hoff' dass ich gleich wieder penn'

At the end of the song, the abbreviated word penn' is used. What is it short for and what does it mean?

I looked for what I expected to be the longer version "pennen" on a couple German to English sites, but only found "kip" as the translation. The answer provided, which is that "pennen" is interchangable with "schlafen" was a great help and also provided me with a dictionary resource to use in the future.

Comment: To close voters: It is not to be expected that we will find an entry for **penn** in a dictionary. Do we really want a disclaimer *"Folks I looked in this and that dictionary but my word is not listed"* on each and every word request? If you don't want to see any of these questions at all please discuss this on Meta. http://meta.german.stackexchange.com/questions/698/research-effort-revisited

Comment: I explained why I asked this question here and could not find the answer myself.

Comment: Ah, your dictionaries were [not completely wrong](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/kip?q=kip#kip-4), but also not very helpful.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a short form for *pennen* (*Ich penn' ↔ Ich penne*) and means *schlafen*.

It's also at [dict.cc](http://www.dict.cc/?s=pennen).

Concerning etymology, it's origin is vague. From [dwds.de](http://dwds.de/?qu=pennen):

> **pennen Vb. ‘schlafen’**, umgangssprachlich (19. Jh.) aus der Gaunersprache; vielleicht zu jidd. pannai ‘müßig’, hebr. penaj ‘(freie) Zeit’, eigentl. ‘Zeit zur Muße’, wenn nicht besser Ableitung von ²Penne f. ‘Kneipe, schlechte Herberge, Schlafstelle’ (Anfang 19. Jh.), älter Benne (Mitte 18. Jh.); aus der Gaunersprache, vgl. Bonne ‘ein Haus, wo Spitzbuben ein und aus gehen’ (Ende 17. Jh.); auch stille Penne ‘Gefängnis, Zuchthaus’ (dieses nach zigeunerisch štilepen ‘Gefängnis’ ?). Vielleicht zu jidd. bono ‘er hat gebaut’, binjan ‘Bau, Gebäude’ (hebr. binjāh, binjān). Dazu Pennbruder m. ‘Landstreicher’ (Ende 19. Jh.) und Penner m. ‘Landstreicher, Schlafmütze’ (Anfang 20. Jh.).